# Content under UINavigationBar & UITabBar

Tags: ios, swift4

[image: Content under bars]

I have a UINavigationController embedded inside a UITabBarController.

The problem is that my content always appears underneath the bars. I have a collection view with x & y set to 0 which appears fine. The green view however is just a simple UIView with the same x & y positions.

My question is, how can I make the content properly show at the expected y coordinate of 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `isTranslucent` property to false on both the navigation bar and the tab bar.

For the nav bar:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

For the tab bar:

```
tabBarController.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Where you do this will depend on how your code is structured, but the easiest spot for each will likely be right after you initialize the tab bar controller and the navigation controller.

Comment: Thankyou! I found that doing this on the custom navigation controller class wasn’t working in viewDidLoad. I moved it to the willShow method of the navigationController class and it worked perfectly.